# How can I save canvas into image by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I  save canvas into image by using JavaScript ?, 
When I am using  local image into canvas, It converting to Image properly But when I am using server image url in canvas it’s not convert into image it showing “Dom exception error”
Or
It is possible to convert DIV into image…
Kindly help with this

Thanks…

Comment: If the image URL is from a domain that is different from the domain of the page, then you cannot get the image data from the `<canvas>` object.